# Unable to set up and connect to IoT Edge Modbus Module

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, pymodbus

I am trying to set up simple simulation where my IoT Edge Device receives Modbus over IP from device and sends this data to my IoT Hub.

Following microsoft tutorial I was able provision IoT Edge Device with X509 self-sighned auth type. After that I added to it Modbus module provided by Azure as Marketplace module.
[image: image-modules]

I modified module twin identity a little by adding SlaveConfig for data I'm expecting to get:

```json
"SlaveConfigs": {
    "Slave01": {
        "SlaveConnection": "localhost",
        "HwId": "SimulatedDevice-01",
        "Operations": {
            "Op01": {
                "PollingInterval": "1000",
                "UnitId": "1",
                "StartAddress": "0",
                "Count": "2",
                "DisplayName": "SensorData"
            }
        }
    }
},
"PublishInterval": "2000"
```

But when I go to ModbusModule and press troubleshoot(or open logs via bash) I get this error message:

```
Desired property change:
{"properties":{"desired":{"PublishInterval":"2000","SlaveConfigs":{"Slave01":{"SlaveConnection":"localhost","HwId":"SimulatedDevice-01","Operations":{"Op01":{"PollingInterval":"1000","UnitId":"1","StartAddress":"0","Count":"2","DisplayName":"SensorData"}}}}}},"$version":5}
No configuration found in desired properties, look in local...
No configuration found in local file.
Saving reported properties: {"PublishInterval":null,"SlaveConfigs":null}
IoT Hub module client initialized.
Desired property change:
{"properties":{"desired":{"SlaveConfigs":{"Slave01":{"SlaveConnection":"localhost","HwId":"SimulatedDevice-01","Operations":{"Op01":{"PollingInterval":"1000","UnitId":"1","StartAddress":"0","Count":"2","DisplayName":"SensorData"}}}},"PublishInterval":"2000"}},"$version":5}
No configuration found in desired properties, look in local...
No configuration found in local file.
Saving reported properties: {"PublishInterval":null,"SlaveConfigs":null}
```

Not sure if this helps but this is my simulated Modbus server:

```py
from pymodbus.server import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
 
import random
 
# Create a data block initialized with two values
block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [random.randint(20, 25), random.randint(30, 40)])
 
# Create a slave context with the data block
slaves = {
    0x01: ModbusSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block)
}
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=slaves, single=True)
 
# Create a Modbus device identification
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName = 'Mdb'
identity.ProductCode = 'Modbus Server'
identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/username/repo'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'
 
# Start the Modbus TCP server
StartTcpServer(context=context, identity=identity, address=('localhost', 502))
```

When I tried to run in order: Start simulated server > Start IoT Edge Device, it did not work but I guess that is expected since there are problems with Modbus module.

Is there problem with how I configured my stuff or did I make some mistake while creating and provisioning it?

Comment: Refer this module identities and update module twins using the [Azure IoT Hub device SDK for Python](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/module-twins-python.md).

Comment: Modbus with azure IoT hub refer [this](https://github.com/erhan-namli/modbus-master-service-azure/blob/main/README.md)